# C# Search items in a ListBox1

Tags: c#, search, listbox

I want to do a search item in the ListBox1 via TextBox4.
Example in this video - rewind time 7.20 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J-D4OzfX7Y; 
But I do not have dataBase. I have a class in which to store data. 
And I do not know how to perform a search to find the item I need. File - 
http://dropmefiles.com/bVrnX  ,
`Foreach - Error, could not convert char type to string`, [Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxpyq.png),[Form1See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3deOV.png) , [Form2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqRDw.png).Could you write code on TextBox4, if it doesn't complicate you. I wrote the TextBox4 code wrong, so please correct it

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts == null)
            Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts = new List<Account>();

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts != null)
        {
       foreach (var account in Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(account);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2(listBox1).Show();
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts != null)
        {
            foreach (var account in Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts)
            {


                var registrationsList = account.Name;


                listBox1.BeginUpdate();
                listBox1.Items.Clear();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))
                {
                    foreach (string str in registrationsList)
                    {
                        if (str.Contains(textBox4.Text))
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add(str);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    listBox1.Items.Add(account); //there is no any filter string, so add all data we have in Store

                listBox1.EndUpdate();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the class of those `Accounts`? The code just says `var`...

Comment: I wrote the TextBox4 code wrong, so please correct it

Comment: foreach    -   could not convert char type to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting couldn't convert chartype to string exception because you're calling foreach on the Account.Name string itself, which iterates through each character in the account name. I've rewritten the method to properly update the listBox1 for the filter string.

```
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts != null)
    {
        listBox1.BeginUpdate();
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))
        {
            foreach (var account in Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts)
            {
                if (account.Name.Contains(textBox4.Text))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(account);
                }
            }

        }
        else //there is no any filter string, so add all data we have in Store
        {
            foreach (var account in Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(account);
            }
        }

        listBox1.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```